# Excel VBA remove one row above number in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have numbers in column A. I am trying to develop VBA code to search for each number in column A and remove one row above once there is a number in column A. Example:

Number in A18 -> remove row number 17

Number in A21 -> remove row number 20

Number in A33 -> remove row number 32

This code is for inserting one row above value in column A. I have tried to modify it for deleting:

```
Dim r6 As Range, r7 As Range
Set printareaP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricelist")

With printareaP.Range("Print_Area")


   For Each r6 In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsEmpty(r6.Value) Then
        If r7 Is Nothing Then
            Set r7 = r6
        Else
            Set r7 = Union(r7, r6)
        End If
    End If
Next r6

If r7 Is Nothing Then
Else
    r7.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

I am getting an error on:

```
Set r7 = Union(r7, r6)
```

----------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------

I have came up with this code:

```
    With printareaP.Range("Print_Area")

    For Each Cell In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
        .Cells(Cell.Row - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: "can't get it work" is not terribly helpful. Please be more specific.

Comment: All you're doing is deleting r7 which is the same as r6. Perhaps you need OFFSET.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need the union and stuff. Also, you are evaluating IsEmpty, which is something else as IsNumeric. I've added a solution for your question below. Your current code is not written to do what you've asked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my proposal:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim r6 As Range, r7 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim printareaP As Range, Cell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricelist")



LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set printareaP = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 1))

For Each Cell In printareaP
    If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
        ws.Cells(Cell.Row - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next Cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Good one Lambik, anyway, I was checking and think that modifying  your line " If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then" with " If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) And Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then" will work as required

Answer (score 1):

## Delete Row Above

### Tips

- While developing code for deleting it is better to use
  **.Hidden=True** instead of .Delete.
- You can use **Not** (like you did with Empty) to choose the opposite (Union).
- When deleting a row above it is best to start from **A2**, because if it
  is found in A1 an error will occur.

### Remarks

- You forgot to include **Numeric**.
- You forgot to close the **With** statement (**End WIth**).
- You forgot to set the row **Offset**.
- You have used the fastest approach by using **Union**.

### The Code

It is assumed that **Print_Area** contains the relevant part of column **A**. If otherwise, remove `.Range("Print_Area")` from the code.

```
Sub DeleteRowAbove()

    Dim r6 As Range, r7 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricelist").Range("Print_Area")

        For Each r6 In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not IsEmpty(r6) And IsNumeric(r6) Then
                If r7 Is Nothing Then
                    Set r7 = r6.Offset(-1, 0)
                  Else
                    Set r7 = Union(r7, r6.Offset(-1, 0))
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End With

    If Not r7 Is Nothing Then
        r7.EntireRow.Delete ' .Hidden = True 
        Set r7 = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

**Nice approach. Keep up the good work.**